# Alignment of Items in GroupBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tablelayout, groupbox

I have been looking around for a solution to this but fail to find it anywhere.

I am currently making a management program for an organization which handles kids with special needs. They need to keep track of a lot of data, etc.

I have placed the data in a GroupBox with TableLayout using Drag N' Drop. However the elements do not align. The left side seems to be docked in the upper left corner of a cell while the right side seems to be docked in the lower right corner of a cell.

How would I solve this so they are both centered in their respective cell?

[image: cells not aligning correctly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment of controls placed in a TableLayout cell can be influenced by the anchor setting of these controls.

You can align your controls **Middle-Center** by setting the **Anchor** property of your Labels and TextBoxes to **None**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really frustrating but it makes sense as the table is now the new parent to dock to.